# Node JS, Express Structure and Require Confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This has been driving me crazy. I'm new to NodeJS. I love it so far but some things have been throwing me off. I was handed a very basic starting point to a node project and I'm unsure how to search google for this.

```
//myapp/server.js

var config  = require('./config');
var app     = express();
var api     = require('./app/routes/api')(app, express); // <-- this?

app.use('/', api);

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('\n============================');
    console.log(' Server Running on Port 3000  ');
    console.log('============================\n');
});
```

Then there's the api.js file that contains the routes.

```
//myapp/app/routes/api.js

var config   = require('../../config');
var mysql    = require('mysql');

module.exports = function(app, express) {

    var api = express.Router();

    api.all('/', function(req, res) {...});

    api.all('/route-two', function(req, res) {...});

    api.all('/another-route', function(req, res) {...});

    return api;
}
```

Ideally I'd like to break up what's going on here into a more organized structure but, I want to understand what I'm doing exactly.

The main thing that is confusing me is this line

```
var api = require('./app/routes/api')(app, express);
```

I was unaware that you can have `()()` next to each other without a `.` or something joining them. Can someone explain what is happening?

Also what is the point of `(app, express)`? It appears that `app` and `express` are getting passed to the `api` part of the application so it's scope can be reached? Am I way off?

If there is a cleaner approach to this I would love to get some insight. I appreciate any thoughts.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**
To make sure I am understanding...

```
var api = require('require this file')(params available to this file);
```

Moving any requires from `api.js` to `server.js` then include those as parameters

```
var api = require('./app/routes/api')(config, app, express, mysql);
```

---

**EDIT**

After more helpful feedback from @AhmadAssaf @Gurbakhshish Singh and @guy mograbi

Modules I want to use in another file other than where they are `require()`ed should be passed in through the second set of `()`

```
//.server.js
var config = require('./config');
var app    = express();                                          
var api    = require('./app/routes/api')(config, app, express); 
                                           |      |        |
                              _____________/______/________/
                             /      /      /
//.app/routes/api.js         |      |      |
module.exports = function(config, app, express) {

    var api = express.Router();

    // code to handle routes
}
```

Could be wrong with this part but based on what I think I am understanding.

```
//.server.js
var config = require('./config');
var app    = express();

var register = require('./app/routes/register')(config, app, express); 
var login    = require('./app/routes/login')(config, app, express); 
                                               |      |        |
                              _________________/______/________/
                             /      /      /
//.app/routes/login.js      |      |      |
module.exports = function(config, app, express) {...handle login...}

//.app/routes/register.js    
module.exports = function(config, app, express) {...handle registration...}    

etc. etc.
```

Hopefully my thinking is about right. I appreciate everyones help on this! :)

Comment: yes that's how they get injected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically you have to understand few thing

- `module.exports` wraps a Javascript object and export it to be used as a pluggable piece of code around a node.js application
- The wrapped javascript object can be a JSON object, Javascript variable, function, etc.

What you have up there in the `api` module is a function that takes two parameters. When you require that module you want to pass some constructors to that function and thats the use of the second () after the module name in the first ()

requiring `express` once in your program and passing the variable around is more or less a singleton pattern. What you can also do is pass the `config` object as well to the `api` module instead of requiring it again :)

Comment: Ok so it's kind of like a `require('./this/file').module.exports(app, express)` 

I can then instead adding requires to sub files I can have them all in the server.js 

`require('./this/file')(config, app, express, mysql)`? Placing the mysql requires in the server.js for organization?

Comment: @Trozdol i did not understand wht you mean by `require('./this/file').module.exports(app, express)`. `module.exports` exposes a chunk of javascript code as a module and `require` will "import" that module. As for your second question, you can have all the requires in your server and start passing them around, but its not clean. What i do is require each module when its needed, and if you need a config, or option object that is `singleton` then i do that once and pass it around

Comment: @Trozdol have a look here https://github.com/ahmadassaf/chatter/blob/master/server.js its a sample of some code i did, you can check the various exports and requires

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. I made edits to my post to hopefully better explain my question here. Just saw your comment on  including modules till needed after the edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
var api = require('./app/routes/api')(app, express);
```

is Equivalent to:

```
var myFunc = require('./app/routes/api');
var api = myFunc(app, express);
```

and becauase of NodeJS's module loading procedure, the require('...') will be 
plugged in by the piece of code that was exported at the path, it can be a object, function, simple variable, etc.

And as far as ()() goes the require() nodeJS will make it something like function(){}() in your case and this is valid javascript and rather very useful to write IIFE(Immediately-Invoked Function Expression) code

Comment: And i forgot to mention that the app and express are injected in because you don't want multiple instanced of these

Comment: This is called the singleton pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: I am familiar with singleton pattern, The only reason i hesitated to use the term is because its one of the design pattern of OOP programming and even though you can achieve similar behavior JS is not exactly OOP

Answer (score 1):

## Quesiton 1

`explain ()()`

every language where a function can return a function you can have this syntax. imagine the following

```
function world(){ ... }

function hello(){
     return world;
}

 // ===> 
hello()() // ==> would invoke hello and then world.
```

So when you see `require('..')()` then it means `require('..')` returns a function. You do this by writing the following:

```
module.exports = function(){}
```

and that function returns yet another function - in your case this means `express.Router();` returns a function.

## Question 2

`is there a cleaner way to write this?`

this is a discussion.. which is hard to answer. depends on your preferences. The only thing I can think of that might help you reach an answer is to use the express generator and see the structure the express team uses.. which is probably as clean as it gets.

express can generate a project for you with some code to start with. simply install it with `npm install -g express` and then run `express` - it will generate the project for you in the same directory where you ran it.

go over the generated project. I suggest follow the same pattern - this is what i do whenever i cick-off a project.

If something is still unclear or if you need me to elaborate, please comment so and I will edit the answer.

Comment: Ok thanks! I think that is making sense. I didn't realize this could be done before today. Seems really handy. Thanks for the explanation! :D

Answer (score 0):

`module.exports` from api.js is a function, which takes two arguments: app, and express. Therefore, when you `require` it in server.js with `require('./app/routes/api')`, the value returned is that function. Since it's a function, you can just call it by putting parentheses after it, and passing in the arguments it expects (app and express), like so : `require('./app/routes/api')(app, express)`.